# Computer freezing on startup with gdm3 after possible package issues

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, kernel

(Ubuntu 20.04)

Hey there guys. Been working on this issue for a bit recently but I haven't really had much luck.

Initially I had some issues, I was trying to install wine32, and it accidentally reverted (as a best guess) a bunch of packages
I try and reboot and, oops, my display manager is missing! Now, why exactly all this happened isn't really what I'm trying to delve into, but the answer seemed simple enough, right? Just reinstall gdm3 (or, to be safe, ubuntu-desktop). So, I went ahead and did just that in recovery mode, except there were some issues with some mesa drivers. Ubuntu desktop wanted (IIRC 10.20.5 or something) while apt was going to install 10.21.123123123~git, or something like that. I'm not entirely sure.
Some aptitude changes, policy edits later, and I'm able to reinstall ubuntu-desktop. I choose gdm3 again, and.... great! The login screen is up, but everything is frozen. Tried reinstalling nvidia drivers, but that didn't seem to help.

I'm guessing the reason for this is some broken packages I accrued along the way. But I can't really figure out exactly what's gone wrong :(. I'm hoping someone can make more sense of this journalctl output than I can.

Currently, if I launch recovery mode on my usual kernel, (5.11.0-31-generic) it likes to hang on `nvidia-gpu: i2c timeout error`, or just generally bug out, so I'm running it on a lower kernel.

I'm really trying to avoid a complete reinstall, given how many gigabytes and gigabytes of files I've accrued on this pc that I fear might get lost

Here's a pastebin link of the journalctl output for the most recent time I tried to start up my pc. https://pastebin.com/813ZMxX1

Thanks in advance to anyone gracious enough to read through this <3

Answer (score 1):

**Some kind of solved:**
After continuing to delve into the problem, I realized that `xserver-xorg-input`, and `xserver-xorg-input-hwe` weren't installed.

So I installed the meta packages for them, and the system seems to be, for the most part, working. Some small bugs here and there, but my initial issue is solved.